# При попытке подключения proxy к request, выдается такая ошибка: TypeError: Cannot mix str and non-str arguments

Tags: python, requests, proxy

Полный код ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\projects\freelance\tiu-comp\tiu-tov-parser.py", line 133317, in <module>
    responses = requests.get(urll, proxies=proxies[proxynum])
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 412, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 304, in get_connection
    proxy = prepend_scheme_if_needed(proxy, 'http')
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 910, in prepend_scheme_if_needed
    scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = urlparse(url, new_scheme)
  File "C:\python\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 389, in urlparse
    url, scheme, _coerce_result = _coerce_args(url, scheme)
  File "C:\python\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 122, in _coerce_args
    raise TypeError("Cannot mix str and non-str arguments")
TypeError: Cannot mix str and non-str arguments
```

Из своего кода убрал список url и список прокси, поставил по одной позиции:

```
proxies = [{
    "ip": "23.225.160.10",
    "port": 3128,
    "hostname": "23.225.160.10",
    "http": 1,
    "https": 0,
    "socks4": 0,
    "socks5": 0,
    "level": 3,
    "yandex": 0,
    "google": 0,
    "mailru": 0,
    "twitter": 0,
    "country_code": "CN",
    "response": 245,
    "good_count": 941,
    "bad_count": 12,
    "last_check": "2021-03-23 14:52:32",
    "city": "",
    "region": "",
    "real_ip": "23.225.160.10",
    "test_time": 0.9,
    "me": 0
}]

catrgoryurl = ["https://tiu.ru/Sport-i-otdykh"]

urls = []
i = 1
proxynum = 1


i = 1
print(proxynum)
print(proxies[proxynum])
for urll in catrgoryurl:
    if (i // 200) > 1:
        i = 0
        proxynum = proxynum + 1
        print(proxies[proxynum])
    z = str(i)
    print(urll)
    responses = requests.get(urll, proxies=proxies[proxynum])
    soups = BeautifulSoup(responses.text, 'lxml')
    i = i + 1
    hhhref = soups.find_all("a", class_="productTile__tileLink--204An")

    for href in hhhref:
        url = href.get('href')
        urls.append(url)
        print(url)
        print(href)
    print(i)



    ipp = soups.find_all('button', class_="ek-button ek-button_height_1-1 ek-button_weight_normal ek-button_theme_white")
    z = []
    for p in ipp:
        z.append(p.text)
    if len(z) >= 3:
        print(z)
        print(z[-2])
        num = int(z[-2]) + 1
        print(num)
        for r in range(2, num):
            znum = ";" + str(r)
            xurll = urll + znum
            responses = requests.get(xurll, proxies=proxies[proxynum])
            r = r + 1
            soups = BeautifulSoup(responses.text, 'lxml')

            hhhref = soups.find_all("a", class_="productTile__tileLink--204An")
            i = i + 1
            print(i)

            for href in hhhref:
                url = href.get('href')
                urls.append(url)
                print(url)



with open("sportall12.txt", 'w') as filehandle:  
    json.dump(urls, filehandle)
```

Все работало, пока я не сделал смену прокси, после обработки определенного количества ссылок. Без прокси реквест работает.
Полный вывод:

```
1
{'ip': '200.53.9.107', 'port': 3128, 'hostname': '200.53.9.107', 'http': 0, 'https': 1, 'socks4': 0, 'socks5': 0, 'level': 1, 'yandex': 0, 'google': 0, 'mailru': 0, 'twitter': 1, 'country_code': 'BR', 'response': 404, 'good_count': 31, 'bad_count': 6, 'last_check': '2021-03-23 14:52:23', 'city': 'Арарангуа', 'region': 'Santa Catarina', 'real_ip': '200.53.9.107', 'test_time': 1.4, 'me': 0}
https://tiu.ru/Sport-i-otdykh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\projects\freelance\tiu-comp\tiu-paser.py", line 133319, in <module>
    responses = requests.get(urll, proxies=proxies[proxynum])
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 412, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 304, in get_connection       
    proxy = prepend_scheme_if_needed(proxy, 'http')
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 910, in prepend_scheme_if_needed
    scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = urlparse(url, new_scheme)
  File "C:\python\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 389, in urlparse
    url, scheme, _coerce_result = _coerce_args(url, scheme)
  File "C:\python\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 122, in _coerce_args
    raise TypeError("Cannot mix str and non-str arguments")
TypeError: Cannot mix str and non-str arguments
```

Comment: Конкретно с этой прокси ошибки нет. Возьмите участок кода на котором вылетает ошибка в блок `try:` чтобы поймать момент вылета и в `except:` напечатайте содержимое `proxies[proxynum]`, чтобы было что анализировать. Там что-то с полями не то у той конкретной прокси на которой вылетает. Что именно - я так не могу догадаться, ошибка довольно необычная.

Comment: А, ну в принципе у вас все прокси и url печатаются перед использованием, так что просто покажите именно тот прокси и тот url, на которых выходит ошибка, самые последние из выведенных на печать.

Comment: Вот полный вывод

Comment: @CrazyElf Вывело это:

Comment: {'ip': '200.53.9.107', 'port': 3128, 'hostname': '200.53.9.107', 'http': 0, 'https': 1, 'socks4': 0, 'socks5': 0, 'level': 1, 'yandex': 0, 'google': 0, 'mailru': 0, 'twitter': 1, 'country_code': 'BR', 'response': 404, 'good_count': 31, 'bad_count': 6, 'last_check': '2021-03-23 14:52:23', 'city': 'Арарангуа', 'region': 'Santa Catarina', 'real_ip': '200.53.9.107', 'test_time': 1.4, 'me': 0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем при таких настройках прокси работает:

```
"http": 1,
"https": 0,
```

А при таких падает:

```
"http": 0,
"https": 1,
```

Почему так, надо разбираться. С ходу могу предложить либо попробовать менять настройки на рабочие прямо на ходу, либо пропускать такие прокси. Завтра попробую более глубоко разобраться.